# how to add an external jquery script to tinymce internal text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tinymce

Hello Everybody i have this problem ,i have jquery tinymce tool which i apply it to a textarea

and i have this jquery [jquery-hashtags](https://github.com/lookapanda/jquery-hashtags) which allow me to make the text just like facebook hashtags ex:**#hashtag**

you can see a preview [here](https://lookapanda.github.io/jquery-hashtags/)

but i can't use it in the tinymce tool
please if anybody can help me with this

here is my code in `<head>` area:

```
   <link href="css/jquery.hashtags.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="js/jquery.hashtags.js"></script>
```

and here is my code in `<body>` area:

```
    <textarea id="Selector">
```

and here is my script area:

```
     <script>
    $(tinymce.activeEditor.getBody()).hashtags();
    $("#tinymce").hashtags();
    $("#Selector").hashtags();
</script>
```

> nethier of this lines works

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#Selector',
        plugins: [
          'advlist autolink lists link image charmap  preview hr anchor pagebreak',
          'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
          'insertdatetime media nonbreaking  table contextmenu directionality',
          'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker  imagetools'
        ],

        content_css:"css/jquery.hashtags.css",



        toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
        toolbar2: ' preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons',
        image_advtab: true,
        templates: [
          { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
          { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
        ],
    });
        </script>
```

so please how can i add this jquery to tinymce tool

Answer (score 1):

This does not work because of the fact that you are operating on a non-visible textarea element. Tinymce takes this textarea, initializes a new iframe for the editor and hides the former editor source element (in your case a textarea).

Comment: so how can I solve this problem? I just want to make after hashtag character '#' text color blue and reference to a link

Comment: i do not know what your hashtag plugin does. but you could try to apply it to the editor body using: $(tinymce.get('Selector').getBody()).hashtags();